# LINQ select items incide List of Lists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, linq

I will show some code first, and then I'll try to tell what I want.

```
Thread thread = db.Threads
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name == name);

var threadTopics = db.Topics
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.ThreadId == thread.Id && x.PinType != PinType.Advertisement)
            .ToList();

thread.Topics = threadTopics;
```

Basically, I want my thread with topics, but I don’t need all topics, I need only "not advertisement" topics. This works for me, but I feel I can do this with one request, but I don't know how.

I tried this, but it's not working:

```
Thread thread = db.Threads
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x=>x.Name == name)
            .Select(x=> new Thread
            {
                Topics = x.Topics.Select(x=>x.PinType != PinType.Advertisement)
            });
```

Models:

```
class Thread {
    int ThreadId {get;set;} 
    ICollection<Topic> Topics {get;set;}
}
class Topic {
    int TopicId {get;set;}  
    int ThreadId {get;set;}
    Thread Thread {get;set;}    
    PinType PinType {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Showing your models would help to understand your relationships (and SO is not a social chat site :)

Comment: No, this won't work. I cant use Topics.PinType, couse Topics is Collection, i need Topic to check PinType.

Comment: Then you would need an `.Where(x => x.Topics.Any(y => y.PinType != PinType.Advertisement))`

Comment: I did in two steps: Thread thread = db.Threads.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name == name), and thread.Topics = thread.Topics.Where(x => x.PinType != PinType.Advertisement).ToList(). Your suggestions not selecting topics, they (if i udnerstad this right) like conditions for selecting Thread, but they still select all topics.

Comment: If you want to include only Topics meeting the condition, then you need to project it into another view model or anonymous type (EF cannot partially load an association property)

Comment: Ye, i tried it with  Select(x=> new Thread  {      Topics = x.Topics.Select(x=>x.PinType != PinType.Advertisement)
            }), but it not worked well. I thought it's possible to do this in one request.

Comment: So what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread thread = db.Threads
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Where(x => x.Name == name)
        .Select(x => new Thread
                         {
                             Topics = x.Topics
                                       .Select(x => x.PinType != PinType.Advertisement)
                         });
```

The left side is `Thread` where the right side is `IEnumerable<Thread>`. And you also miss the `Id` in new `Thread`.

Change it to:

```
var threads = db.Threads
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(x => x.Name == name)
                .Select(x => new Thread
                                 {
                                     ThreadId = x.ThreadId,
                                     Topics = x.Topics
                                               .Where(x => x.PinType != PinType.Advertisement)
                                               .ToList()
                                 });
```

Maybe you need

```
Thread thread = threads.FirstOrDefault();
```

Then we can simplify this to

```
Thread thread = db.Threads
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Where(x=>x.Name == name)
        .Select(x=> new Thread
        {
            ThreadId = x.ThreadId,
            Topics = x.Topics.Where(x=>x.PinType != PinType.Advertisement).ToList()
        }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Topics = x.Topics.Select(x=>x.PinType != PinType.Advertisement) here error, 'cannot convert IEnumerable<bool> to ICollection<Topic>. And if i use Where instead of Select - it cannot convert IEnumerable<Topic> to ICollection<Topic>.

Answer (score 0):

This is working like I wanted. First i looking for Thread i need, and after i found it - i remove some Topics from it. I wanted to do this in one request, but i think this 'ok' too.

```
Thread thread = db.Threads
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name == name);

thread.Topics = thread.Topics.Where(x => x.PinType != PinType.Advertisement).ToList();
```